# php pdo prepared statements: bindParam doesn't work

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

why this doesn't work:

```
public function query($query, $vars = array())
{
    $link = $this->getLink();
    if($link)
    {
        $stmt = $link->prepare($query);
        if($stmt)
        {
            if(count($vars)>0)
            {
                $count = 1;
                foreach($vars as $v)
                {
                    $stmt->bindParam($count, $v);
                    $count++;
                }
            }
            if($stmt->execute())
                return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

and this works:

```
public function query($query, $vars = array())
{
    $link = $this->getLink();
    if($link)
    {
        $stmt = $link->prepare($query);
        if($stmt)
        {
            if($stmt->execute($vars))
                return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

calling:

```
$result = $db->query('select * from users where user like ? and email like ?',array('my_user', 'myemail@domain.com'));
```

edit with final code:

```
public function query($query, $vars = array())
{
    $link = $this->getLink();
    if($link)
    {
        $stmt = $link->prepare($query);
        if($stmt)
        {
            if(count($vars)>0)
            {
                $count = 1;
                foreach($vars as $v)
                {
                    $stmt->bindValue($count, $v);
                    $count++;
                }
            }
            if($stmt->execute())
                return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that `bindParam` binds a variable (not its value) to a parameter. However, `$v`'s value changes with each iteration of the `for` loop therefore each of your query's parameters would have the last item in the array as their value (not what you want I'm sure).

I would suggest using `bindValue` instead of `bindParam`

Answer (score 1):

I am not extremely familiar with PDO, but it seems you can't bind a variable which changes constantly. Use bindValue instead.

Also note that you should not use LIKE this way. Use `=` instead